# What does "ground line" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading an article on Science about [collecting sound of underwater species](https://www.science.org/content/article/scientists-want-create-library-every-sound-ocean), which is in the Q&A form. Part of this article says:

**Q:** Do your hydrophones ever … float away?

**A:** Oh yeah. In a freshwater bay, I had one I’m pretty convinced someone dragged away. We don’t mark them—otherwise curious people pick them up—but I had a *ground line* running along [this] hydrophone so I could find it later. I think someone [accidentally] put their anchor down and dragged it off somewhere.

I don't understand what the interviewee mean by "*ground line*" here. I cannot imagine what "a ground line running along [this] hydrophone" describes.

Comment: A [line](https://www.lexico.com/definition/line) here is *A length of cord, rope, wire, or other material serving a particular purpose.* The device has no marker, so a line is attached to the shore so that the owner can find it later. To [ground](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ground) something is to *Connect with the ground.*

Comment: I think he means the same thing as a ground cable. However, I don't see how putting one along the hydrophone helps to locate it unless the cable has some electronics in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A groundline is part of a fishing setline that anchors the set to the bed.

[image]

It sounds like similar equipment was used to anchor the recording equipment underwater.